# Paypal plugin integration issue

Tags: php, android, paypal

I am using spinin/phonegap-paypal plugin for my phonegap android app. I downloaded the plugin, integrated with  the mobile app, then tried using the payment on sandbox mode. I was able to do the payment till yesterday. But suddenly it has stopped working. From my app I am able to login to the Paypal account and go to the dashboard, but when I click on 'Send Payment' , I get an error- 'Payment Failed: System Error, Please try again later '. Can anyone please tell me what must be going wrong? Alteast can any one let me know what are the possible reasons for this to happen, so that I can check each of the points on code level.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What API is it using?  Are you getting an actual response back from PayPal with an error code?

Comment: I am using the paypal plugin as mentioned above, the plugin calls its REST API. About the error code, no I am not getting any error code. I simply get the error message that I mentioned. Any clue what must be going wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand, the plugin is not functioning properly.. Since there is nothing that I have changed in the code which will prevent a working application to stop functioning suddenly.. The plugin does not seem reliable.

Comment: Can't speak to that much.  I've been using their Classic API all along and it works just fine, but that would involve building PHP web services or something like that for your JS stuff to communicate with.